# Invalid hook call. React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Import useState from react, paste it to body function, but react tells me Wrong use hooks.
Although another hook works like this.

```
import {getAuth} from 'firebase/auth';
import {useState} from 'react';

const useAuth = () => {

  const [state, setState] = useState(null); //wrong use

  const auth = getAuth();
  const getUserId = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          resolve(user.uid);
        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
      });
    });
  };

  return {
    getUserId,
  };
};

export default useAuth;
```

Comment: did you try importing `React` as well?

Comment: Yes, just tried, its showed me same mistake

Comment: The error message should show you three examples that could cause this kind of error which also includes one option where two different react libs in the same project could cause this. There is not enough infos in your question for us to help you but maybe follow those suggestions

Comment: Other my hooks with same logic works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your returned getUserId is not a jsx. If your function is intended to be a react functionnal component then it is supposed to return a jsx.  If not then you cannot use a react hook like useState.

Comment: Its just example, im tryied with other names

Comment: Perhaps because of i use my custom hook in other custom hook
I imported useAuth to useDatabase, and that resulted in an error about hooks.

Now i remade code and it work for me